# How can "Legendary" badge be awarded on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, daily-reputation-badges

I was looking at the badges available on meta, and noticed the "Legendary" badge has been awarded 4 times (150 x 200 reputation in a day):

[image]

But how is this possible? The reputation on Meta Stack Overflow is just the same as on Stack Overflow, is it something that moderators get (and euhm Servy...) or was it a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Internally, reputation is still tracked on meta sites just as it is on any other site, complete with point values for votes and daily reputation caps. If it were shown, I'd have the number 131k next to my picture instead of 104k...

...But it isn't shown, and mostly isn't used. Instead, your reputation from the main site is periodically mirrored to your profile here, and used for nearly all privileges and other purposes.

Except for the badges that pertain to the rep cap. Those ignore your reputation and look directly at your reputation *history*, which is sitting there in the background, quietly recording every time you hit the cap.

Comment: That explains it :) Where did you check that you have 131K 'hidden' reputation?

Comment: You sure you're running that query on *meta*, @Glorfindel? As for my source... I have access to the internal data used by the badges.

Comment: @Shog9 you're right - I got confused by the meta-icon below the 'Run Query' button.

Comment: I miss the meta reputation change notifications. It helped to curate older posts and kept me in touch with what people were viewing and when.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a bug. Every day, the reputation you would receive *as if Meta Stack Overflow* was a normal site is calculated and if you'd hit the 200 rep cap, it would bring you one step closer to the [Legendary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary) (and [Epic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic)) badge.

For example, if this question would get 40 upvotes today, you'd receive the [Mortarboard badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard).

Sidenote: it is quite hard to see how far you are from hitting the rep cap on a meta site - there is no [Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=reputation) as on the main site.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking where I can find that hidden reputation after reading Shog9's comment

Comment: @AlexanderDerck You can find it using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215919/virtual-meta-reputation-for-user-x). The query doesn't take the daily rep cap into account, though.