# Bring back the reputation user panel in activity summaries for meta profiles

Tags: feature-request, reputation, meta, profile-page

> Internally, reputation is still tracked on meta sites just as it is on any other site, complete with point values for votes and daily reputation caps. If it were shown, I'd have the number 131k next to my picture instead of 104k...
>   -[Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325798/1026459)

The code is already there, as this feature used to exist.

The hooks are already in place in the database and on the server, as the epic badge currently tracks reputation by day, and feeds it to the profile.

[image]

I understand that there is no reputation on meta, but really, it isn't about that so much as this is about **tracking what is going on**. By not giving this signal to hundreds of thousands of users meta is not properly abiding by the overall model that the exchange was built on.

The lack of notification from the reception of previous posts drives the creation of duplicate content. When posts show up in the reputation list for either -2 or +10 most users review them, especially if they are downvoted. This activity often leads to improvement of the post which bumps the question.

Having the already created content bumped gives that content more of a chance at being cultivated and less of a chance at having other similar content created.

[image]

*The graph and expansion are not really as important as merely seeing the recent activity this area provides which would fairly localize the reputation aspect*

tl;dr; Bring back the reputation user panel in activity summaries for meta profiles.

Comment: related: [How can I see my meta reputation history?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266527/839601)

Comment: This isn't quite clear, but I assume you mean that you want your rep tab on Meta to show _votes on your Meta posts_, right? So it wouldn't really be "rep", because that doesn't change in response to Meta votes.

Comment: @gnat - I don't think Oded is correct in his answer there. There is reputation history here on meta.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - You are incorrect. Reputation is tracked here on meta just like main with the same metrics.

Comment: Well, you learn something every day! I'd rather see [something that's about votes rather than rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238766/159251), but your proposal would definitely be better than the current lack of any info.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - This was all I could come up with with regards to showing recent voting activity on user's posts which seemed reasonably scoped. I know it is related to reputation, but voting activity is at the heart of reputation changing so that is where this angle came from.

Comment: I'm with @JoshCaswell. Rep count would provide too much information, especially with losses from down voting answers. But seeing how many votes you get is different, doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @Laurel - "Too much information"? I don't see that being a problem. If an answer reputation count is not divisible by 10 then it had a downvote (sure, questsions are slightly different), and also note that the reputation shown is only the recent change, not the total historical value (just as on main). Furthermore, the reputation tab only shows recent voting, which was the whole point - to see voting activity. Once the voting activity is observed, navigating to the post would allow for seeing the entirety of the vote count if desired.

Comment: @Laurel - Losses from you downvoting other answers do not show up in the reputation tab so that wouldn't be included.

Comment: Part of the reason (the main reason?) for rep is to gamify the question/answer process to drive good content.  But on Meta, upvotes/downvotes are more often used to signal agreement than to judge quality.  I feel exposing meta-rep would not incentivize the sort of feedback meta is designed for.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - That is a common misunderstanding. Meta voting is not to signal agreement for discussions, bug reports, or support posts. Voting does serve that purpose for feature-requests, so it is relevant on this post, but in general you should not be downvoting well researched discussions just because you disagree with the topic.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - Further, with regards to reputation, meta has a rich history of having reputation. Years of it. Only recently was it split off into this non reputation version here, and there is still an entire exchange with reputation at Meta Stack Exchange. They do not suffer from having reputation related issues, so I find your points moot.

Comment: Old MSO did suffer from that issue, as can be readily observed looking at older posts.  MSE (versus MSO) doesn't suffer from issues about gamification only because it's a gated community where most people can not just show up and make a post.

Comment: And voting behavior of agree/disagree on all metas clearly reflects people's expectation, and behavior defines purpose.  You can't declare after the fact that people are voting "wrong".

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - After the fact? It is well discussed. Just because you are unaware doesn't mean that all users are. This topic is also very tangential, please post your own question if you need expansion on meta voting. Also, see this from 2013 which has been essentially the status quo for voting outlook on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193884/178816

Comment: I was there for that discussion you linked to, and I think that the @Conspicuous Compiler makes a good point. Furthermore, it is not merely "tangential" because it is an effective counter-point to your proposal. I think there has been a big advantage in *not* tracking reputation for Meta sites, given the way that Meta sites work. As Shog points out in his answer to the linked question, it's not really that voting is different on Meta, but that *Meta* is different. Given that difference, and the fact that most users don't understand the distinction, why do we need to track/show Meta rep?

Comment: Hmm. Then your question is extremely unclear to me, even after reading it again very carefully. You are pretty explicitly requesting to "bring back the reputation tab", but my reputation tab on main lists all of the changes to my reputation in either timeline or graphical form. It also gives a numerical reputation score. Soooo.....not really sure how your question is completely and unambiguously distinct from "showing reputation". Maybe instead of insulting people, you should take their comments as a sign.

Comment: @CodyGray - I see your misunderstanding, that is my fault. I used the wrong terminology for tab, I will edit an update. I am only taking about the user-panel-reputation element. It is more of a section really. Only in the account summary.

Comment: I have no idea why everyone is so obsessed with reputation here. The post clearly mentions that _it isn't about that so much as this is about **tracking what is going on**_. I would certainly love to see which answers are attracting (up/down)votes and, to date, it is not (easily) possible.

Comment: see also [Can we have upvote/downvote notifications on meta posts back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258179/can-we-have-upvote-downvote-notifications-on-meta-posts-back)